# Parsing only first regex match in a line with several matches

Tags: regex, grep

Is it possible to have a regex that parses only `a1bcdea1` from this line `a1bcdea1ABCa1DEFa1` ?

This grep command does not work:

```
$ cat txtfile
a1bcdea1ABCa1DEFa1
$ grep -oE "[A-Z,a-z]1.*?[A-Z,a-z]1" txtfile
a1bcdea1ABCa1DEFa1
```

I want the output of grep to be only `a1bcdea1`.

EDIT:

It is obvious that I can just use grep -o "a1bcdea1" for the above line, but consider if one has several thousands of lines and the goal is to match FIRST `[A-Z,a-z]1.*?[A-Z,a-z]1` for each single line.

Comment: Can you state your requirements for the string you want to match? Otherwise, why not just `head -c 8 txtfile` or `grep -oE "([a-z]*1){2}"` or even `grep -oE "a1bcdea1"`?

Comment: The string should start with an upper or lower case letter, followed by number 1, followed by any characters any number of times, end with an upper or lower case letter followed by number 1. Basically what `[A-Z,a-z]1.*?[A-Z,a-z]1` is doing.  The entire line `a1bcdea1ABCa1DEFa1` will match my regular expression, but so will its first part :`a1bcdea1`, I want ONLY the first match.

Comment: Will `a1bcdea1` part always be at line start?

Comment: No, it can be literally any uppercase or lower case character as many times: like this `a1dcfa1` or `C1abdrFECsarR1` or `r1uaysdhahsaz1`, etc.

Comment: Will you consider `awk` or `gnu awk` solution?

Comment: @anubhava, Sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a [`^` start anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and restricting character set used:

```
grep -o '^[A-Za-z]1[A-Za-z]*1'
```

[See this Bash demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BPdEwKTklNdHQ0ck50dDF1S3RUF2hRiG9KLVAQRcoHRftqBuVqFsVawhjaBmq//8PAA) or [Regex Pattern at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QyUXHh/1)

If you expect more digits or other characters in between, go [with this](https://regex101.com/r/QyUXHh/2)

```
grep -oP '^[A-Za-z]1.*?[A-Za-z]1'
```

The [lazy](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) matching requires [perl compatible](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs) mode. For not at line start, go [with this](https://regex101.com/r/QyUXHh/3)

```
grep -oP '^.*?\K[A-Za-z]1.*?[A-Za-z]1'
```

[`\K` resets](https://riptutorial.com/regex/topic/1338/match-reset---k) beginning of the reported match and is a PCRE feature as well.

Comment: This is working only when desired match is in the start of a line, it won't work if match is in the middle of a line, please see comment below.

Comment: @A.Razavi In this case you could probably use `grep -oP '^.*?\K[A-Za-z]1.*?[A-Za-z]1'`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `gnu awk` solution using `split` function:

```
awk '(n = split($0, a, /[a-zA-Z]1/, b)) > 1 {print b[1] a[2] b[2]}' file
```

```
a1bcdea1
```

This `awk` command splits each line on regex `/[a-zA-Z]1/` and stores split tokens in array `a` and delimiters in array `b`.

Comment: The awk command is working as expected only when my intended regex is at the beginning of line, for example it won't work for this line `aa(l)e1a[ab](O)a[b]1a(r)eq1qqqqq2-q(n3)[nb]q(q34)qqqq4` where I want the output to be `e1a[ab](O)a[b]1a(r)eq1`

Comment: Ah I had extra `a[1]` in `awk` that was causing wrong result. It is fixed now.